# Geting Rating data from Vivino page with python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am scraping the ranking data from Vivino.
The website is: [link](https://www.vivino.com/explore?e=eJzLLbI11jNVy83MszVXy02ssDU2UEuutPXzUUu2dQ0NUiuwNVRLT7MtSyzKTC1JzFHLT7ItSizJzEsvjk8sSy1KTE9Vy7dNSS1OVisviY4FKgZTRhDKGMozgdDmEMoEAJ7xJhY%3D)
but I got an empty data list can anyone help me. Image of the result i got [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UY7b6.png)

```html
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.vivino.com/explore?e=eJzLLbI11jNVy83MszVXy02ssDU2UEuutPXzUUu2dQ0NUiuwNVRLT7MtSyzKTC1JzFHLT7ItSizJzEsvjk8sSy1KTE9Vy7dNSS1OVisviY4FKgZTRhDKGMozgdDmEMoEAJ7xJhY%3D" #the url of the website we're scraping



page = requests.get(url)
html = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser") 

Name_html = html.find_all(class_="item_description") 
Rating_html = html.find_all(class_="vivinoRating__averageValue--3Navj") 

Name_list = []
Rating_list = []

#loop over HTML elements, get text and add to list   
for i in Name_html:
    Name_list.append(i)

for i in Rating_html:
    Rating_list.append(i)

#make a dictionary with column names for data to put in DataFrame   
data = {"description": Name_list,
        "airdate": Rating_list}
   
df = pd.DataFrame(data)   #make a dataframe
```

Answer (score 0):

The wines labels are loaded through Javascript, you can't scrape them with bs4 as if they're part of a static html.

You need to either manually send the POST `requests` to get the response content, or scrape the page dinamically with `selenium` through any of the available browser simulation drivers (i.e. `chromedriver`).